# Send automated email when Sharepoint list column is changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, flow

I'm setting up a flow to Send automated email when Sharepoint list column is changed to "Completed".

The flow seems straight forward. Flow seems to run but does not send email. Where am I going wrong?
See flow picture below.
Thanks a million for your support.

[image: Imaenter image description herege flow]

Comment: Can you please send the results (screenshot) of flow run from history? Just to see the outputs of all actions in your flow - to ensure your condition works fine.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, 
I realised condition column list has to different due to drop down menu.

Comment: flow and email worked. Thansk again for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow looks fine. i would suggest you check the flow run history to check what's going on:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, checked flow history. Al flows run successful

Comment: You could click the histroy entry, you would see the details of every flow step.